# UnusedNullCheckInEquals : What is the correct way to compare objects by equals method?

Tags: java

```
public class MyObjectList extends ArrayList<MyObject>

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return o != null && o.getClass().equals(this.getClass()) && super.equals(o);
    }
}
```

And after pmd pipelines I have an exception: UnusedNullCheckInEquals Priority:3 Invoke equals() on the object you've already ensured is not null. Ok, I change code a little bit and now the test passed:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    } else if (o == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return o.getClass().equals(this.getClass()) && super.equals(o);
    }
}
```

And maybe it's not so important now but I am just curious if there a "correct" correct way to pass this pmd check without adding extra line...

```
return o != null && o.getClass().equals(this.getClass()) && super.equals(o);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get trapped by `o.getClass().equals(this.getClass())` when objects are proxied.

I'd rather use something like:

```java
return this == o || o instanceof MyObjectList && super.equals(o);
```

`instanceof` returns `false` if `o` is `null`.

Comment: Usage of `instanceof` in `equals` methods for type check should be used with caution, as you might end up with symmetry issues, violating the equals contract (i.e. `a.equals(b)` but not `b.equals(a)`), as `instanceof` is not symmetric. The proxy aspect is however valid as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the order of the calls to pass the test and avoid the redundant `null` check:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (this == o) {
    return true;
  } else if (!super.equals(o)) { // super.equals() will implicitly check for null
    return false;
  } else {
    return o.getClass().equals(this.getClass());
  }
}
```